# How do I Remove Reflections Off a Diffuse BSDF Surface?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, light

[image: Sample Picture]

You can see that the plaster walls are somewhat reflecting the floor (which is 45% glossy, 55% diffuse) and I neither changing the glossy setting in the Ray Visibility for the floor nor the walls fixes it. I've tried upping the roughness, doesn't work. Do you guys have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reflectivity is controlled by surface roughness. The higher the roughness value, the less reflective the surface. Another thing to try is turn off reflective and refractive caustics in the render settings.

Comment: Thanks! That works even better than the alternate solution I found.

Comment: Great, just remember in cycles try and think metallic/roughness :)

Comment: @Jude Don't just thank in the comments, if the answer solved your problem consider marking it as correct, or at least upvote it if it helped you

Comment: @Duarte I have 11 reputation so I can't upvote things. And it wouldn't let me accept the answer at first.

Comment: OK, you will once you have enough reputation don't forget to come back :)

Answer (score -1):

It appears this can be fixed by deselecting "Diffuse" in the Ray Visibility of the floor.